# UML Sequence Diagram BuildOrder.getOrder()

Tags: uml, sequence-diagram

How do I draw a UML Sequence diagram showing the Participants and Method calls for `BuildOrder.getOrder()` in the code:  [Source code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zC6CD.jpg)

Comment: To get more answers, you should explain what the participants are and what the method is supposed to do: not everybody has time to read the code, and even less if it’s provided as a picture ;-)

Comment: @larak In order to get your question reopened you first need to do as requested by Christophe.

Answer (score 1):

A participant `c:Client` that calls an operation `method()` of another participant `o:Order()` is shown in a sequence diagram as a [message](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/interaction-message.html):

[image]

The case of `getOrder()` is a special case in two ways:

- first, it is a static operation, which is not related to a specific instance of the class.  A static operation can nevertheless be shown as a message to an object of the class (see UML quote below).
- second, it creates the order with which you'll interact.  You would therfore show it as a [create message](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/interaction-message.html#create): the arrow is dashed and open headed, and is directed to the box atop of the lifeline:

[image]

---

*Remark: you could just show `«create»`. However, nothing prevents you from specifying precisely the static operation that is called, as the UML specifications explain:*

> Lifelines cannot directly represent Types. However, any Lifeline representing a ConnectableElement with a Type having an Operation with isStatic = true, can accept Messages with a signature associated with that static Operation.

Comment: Very good answer. I have two remarks: _"the box atop of the lifeline"_ is part of the notation of a lifeline, not a separate box. And the create message cannot refer to an operation (constraint `signature_refer_to` states, that a signature refering to an operation implies messagekind is syncCall or asyncCall). Therefore, `<<create>>getOrder()` is merely an arbitrary text with no formal connection to the static operation with this name. Technically, a constructor can only be called _after_ the creation of the object. Even then, the stereotype «create» would not be shown in the message name.

Comment: @AxelScheithauer thank you for your constructive feedback. “the box atop” was meant to be a visual description for a non-uml expert, in my first draft typed on the metro, before I could insert a diagram.  I was not aware of the absence of formal signature on a create message. Fortunately, even if the text is free, it may give a good hont to what static operation will be called. Out of curiosity, if you were to keep only one, would you keep the <<create>> or the factory function name ?

Comment: I would use the `getOrder()` operation name. The `«create»` is already shown by the dashed arrow.